# In Firebase Firestore security rules, i keep getting the a null error message and can't figure out how to fix it

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am receiving the error "Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [11], column [74]. Null value error."

Here are my security rules and am really struggling to see what the issue is:

[image]

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow read access to documents in the "users" collection for authenticated users
    match /users/{documentId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == resource.data.user_id;
    }
    
    // Allow read access to documents in the "clarity" collection, only if userId matches user_id from "users" collection
    match /clarity/{documentId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == get(/databases/$(database)/documents/clarity/$(documentId)).data.userId;
      allow create: if isSignedIn();
    }
  }
}

function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
}
```

I've tried everything to get retrieve the string value from the collection but it doesnt seem to be picking it up and just returning a null value.

There are no null values in the userId fields for all the documents.I've also tried the resource.data.userId method and this gives me the same null error.

Below I have added a screenshot of the error message on the firestore rules playground.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UrVK.png)

Comment: This seems to be loading the current document: `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/clarity/$(documentId))`. You don't need to call `get` to access the current document, but can use `resource` or `request.resource` to access it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've also tried resource.data.userId and request.resource.data.userId and both approaches lead to the same error.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the full error in the rules playground, and the information you are passing in to the call?

Comment: Yes sure, just uploaded. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read `/clarity/{documentId}`, but the playground doesn't do any expansion of that `{documentId}` in there - so it ends up trying to read `/clarity`.

You'll want to pass the document ID in there, so the UID of the user who you're testing with so `/clarity/duZ66...`.

Comment: I think im getting where you're going with this but you answer seemed to get cut off towards the end?

Comment: Okay so you're suggesting i put the specific userId in the match statement? I dont see how that would solve the problem on a larger scale (to more than just this one user id)

Comment: Not the match statement, but the Location field of the rules playground. The path you're trying to read from uses a `{documentId}` variable, and the playground doesn't support variables in that field.